# Jetty - Servlet cannot be found

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jetty

I am new to Servlets and wanted to call a simple Servlet by using Eclipse's Jetty plugin. I can call the index.html, but when trying to access the Servlet I get:

> HTTP ERROR: 404
>   Problem accessing /ProjectServlet. Reason:
>      NOT_FOUND

I think I configured all my files correctly and cannot explain why Jetty returns this error.

Thanks for helping me!

---

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Servlet Call Test:</h1>
    <form action="/ProjectServlet" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="name" maxlength="20" value="Name" onfocus="this.select()"/><br>
        <input type="submit" name="callservlet" value="Call Servlet."/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**ProjectServlet.java**

```
package servlets;


import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ProjectServlet
 */
@WebServlet(description = "Servlet to return JSON response with project list", urlPatterns = { "/ProjectServlet" })
public class ProjectServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public ProjectServlet() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //Call Servlet Button
        if (request.getParameter("callservlet") != null) {

            response.setContentType("application/json");

            String name = request.getParameter("name"); 
            String jsonexample = "hi " + name; 

            response.getWriter().write(jsonexample);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

---

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>Test</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProjectServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.ProjectServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProjectServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ProjectServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: You are using the WebServlet annotation and also defining the servlet in the web.xml. You only need one. I don't know if that is the error, though. Either remove the servlet definition and servlet mapping from the web.xml or remove the WebServlet annotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be as shown below to add the *context path* before Servlet url.

```
<form action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/ProjectServlet" 
         method="GET">
```

instead of

```
<form action="/ProjectServlet" method="GET">
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but still get:
HTTP ERROR 404

Problem accessing /Test/$%7BpageContext.servletContext.contextPath%7D/ProjectServlet. Reason:

    NOT_FOUND

Comment: don't know how are you doing it? It should work. Why contextPath is not replaced as per the exception above.

Comment: move the welcome-file-list entry in the end in web.xml

Comment: This is definitely the source of the error. But I cannot figure out how to define the correct path to the servlet.

Comment: let me try to test it at my end.

Comment: But when defining all the paths the same it works.


web.xml: <url-pattern>servlets/ProjectServlet</url-pattern>
index.html: <form action="servlets/ProjectServlet" method="GET">


It only doesn't work when using a path before the actual servlet.

Answer (score 2):

Use either `web.xml` declaration or use annotation you are using both that's why conflicting situation occurs and 404 has been returned.So either remove annotation or mappings from xml file.

Moreover specify `action` for submit button

```
 <input type="submit" name="callservlet" value="Call Servlet." onClick="action"/>
                                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I have also tried this before. Neither removing the annotation nor removing the mapping works. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

You either need to user relative path (without '/'):

```
<form action="ProjectServlet" method="GET">
```

or full path to the servelt including root context:

```
<form action="/yourRootContext/ProjectServlet" method="GET">
```

If you do not plan to change the root context you can hard code it in the page, otherwise get it using either:

```
Scrplet: action="<%= application.getContextPath() %>/ProjectServlet"
EL: action="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/ProjectServlet"
```

based on your preferences.