# mapping java servlet and action form

Tags: jsp, servlets

I follow the tutorial in this [page](http://www.jansipke.nl/model-view-controller-mvc-with-jsp-and-jstl/). Instead of using web.xml, I am using the annotation @WebServlet("/CoffeeSelect"). However, I have a trouble to understand the servlet-mapping between the form action and java servlet. It is weird but sometimes, I can run the code successfully, but sometimes, I got http 404. If anyone can share some article talk about servlet mapping, I am very appreciated that (I couldn't find a good resource about that).

Comment: I like this one http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/index.html

Comment: thank you. If you have other good resource, please share with me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using plain servlets, action in the form will point to the one of `<url-pattern>` defined for servlet (`/CoffeeSelect` in your case). The 404 errors you may see are usually due to using relative uri from page nested in folder structure. Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/24996563/3701228.
It gets a bit more complicated, when you use web frameworks like JSF, Struts, etc. But thats a different story.

[Basic tutorial about servlets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets.htm#BNAFD)

Comment: Thank you for the tutorial. I like that alot